# PHP Loop does not contain any errors but its not working either. Here's my code:

Tags: php, html

My while loop not working, I also have a while loop on the same PHP page, but this one doesn't working, I dont understand why. Heres my code:

```
$posts_query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id";
$posts_result = mysqli_query($connection, $posts_query);

<ul class="accordion__wrapper">
               <?php while ($post_side = mysqli_fetch_assoc($posts_result)) : ?>
                  <?php
                  $category_id = $post_side['category_id'];
                  $category_query = "SELECT category_name FROM categories WHERE id=$category_id";
                  $category_result = mysqli_query($connection, $category_query);
                  $category = mysqli_fetch_assoc($category_result);
                  ?>
                  <li class="accordion__menu accordion__products-bg">
                     <button class="accordion__effect accordion__products-btn">
                        <?= $category['category_name'] ?>
                     </button>
                     <div class="accordion__panel accordion__products-list">
                        <p>
                           <a href="#articleOne" data-localscroll="true">Artikel 1</a>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                           <a href="#articleTwo" data-localscroll="true">Artikel 2</a>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                           <a href="#articleThree" data-localscroll="true">Artikel 3</a>
                        </p>
                     </div>
                  </li>
               <?php endwhile ?>
            </ul>
```

Its not showing any error, and the

doesn't show either...

Comment: Use `var_dump` to see what is coming back from the database

Answer (score 0):

Already solved, the problem was happen because I try to the same variable with only one call.. But I think there should be another way that can siplify it

$categories_query = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id";
$categories_result = mysqli_query($connection, $categories_query);

$side_categories_query = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id";
$side_categories_result = mysqli_query($connection, $side_categories_query);

```
    <?php
          $no = 1;
          while ($category = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories_result)) : ?>
             <button class="product__top-btn products-btn-<?= $no; ?>">
                <?= $category['category_name'] ?>
             </button>
    <?php $no++;
          endwhile ?>
    <?php $no = 1;
          while ($side_category = mysqli_fetch_assoc($side_categories_result)) 
          : ?>
            <div class="accordion__menu accordion__products-bg">
                <button class="accordion__effect accordion__products-btn">
                   <?= $side_category['category_name'] ?>
                </button>
            </div>
    <?php $no++;
          endwhile ?>
```